# Bootstrap JS bugged..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i got some problems with bootstrap, i tried to use stuff like Modal, Popover or tooltip,

but some bugs are:
Modal: Backround overlay is above the modal(makes everything including modal darker)
Tooptip: Ignores the alignment of it, like top.
Popover: Wont work at all.
I copied the examples of bootstrap straight into my website, still dont works.

i'll include the need codes:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://data.[CENSORED].net/css/flat-ui.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://data.[CENSORED].net/css/custom.css">
 
<!-- Jscript collection -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- /Jscript collection -->

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>
```

i use the newest JS of bootstrap and the newest JQuery.

I didnt include the whole sourcecode, since it isnt needed, you only needed what i use(Tooltip and popover) and it only needs the Jquery part.

hard to explain but yeah.

Comment: Can you make a demo with a problem?

Comment: Make sure you loaded up the css for bootstrap, check it out: http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: the CSS were added before, i added it now to the snipet.

Answer (score 5):

From your sample code, you haven't included the **CSS** which is vital in setting the tooltip to `position: absolute`. Furthermore, you'll also need to explicitly initialise the tooltip yourself, the `data-toggle` example is just a suggestion of how you might handle it:

> For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt-in, meaning you must initialize them yourself. One way to initialize all tooltips on a page would be to select them by their data-toggle attribute:

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
});
```

([source](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/))

**Working Code**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://data.[CENSORED].net/css/flat-ui.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://data.[CENSORED].net/css/custom.css">
 
<!-- Jscript collection -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
      placement: "bottom"
    });
  });
  $(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
      placement: "bottom"
    });
  });
</script>

<!-- /Jscript collection -->

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>
```

Comment: The CSS was included in the HTML page before, I added it now to the snipet so you can see it.

Comment: Okay somehow i got the code working, i put the jscript in the head before, but it didnt worked but somehow now it works, but the next problem is, like seen in CSS i use Flat-UI but with it the Popover dont shows the content, nor title.. what now?

Comment: Now you either try to solve that issue, or you consider writing another question. Before doing so however, you should read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Rubber duck problem solving](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/)

Comment: I actually 'Solved' it, it worked fine, the title and content is just white, same as the popover, now i gotta find out how i change the popover text color.

Comment: Welp, fixed it, but idk how i get it to the 'default' colour.

Comment: If this is the right answer to your *original* question, please consider marking it as such.